# Javascript toExponential(3) with E in upper case

Tags: javascript, uppercase

I'm showing a result witht this expression:

```
textelement = document.createTextNode(array[index].toExponential(3));
```

and it shows, for instance:

```
5.636e+9
```

Is there any way to show this result with an uppercase E, picking up this result: 5.636E+9?

In other words: How turn this 'e' into an 'E'?

I've tried this:

```
.toExponential(3)).toLocaleUpperCase();
```

but fails.

Any idea?

Comment: why you didn't use direct replace method .replace("e","E");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toExponential(3)).toLocaleUpperCase();` won't work because you are calling `toLocaleUpperCase()` on the result of this statement:

```
document.createTextNode(array[index].toExponential(3));
```

which doesn't return a string, instead you need to call `toLocaleUpperCase()` or `toUpperCase()` on the result of the `toExponential()` method itself, so that the resulting string is modified before it is inserted into HTML tree.

You can do it like this:

```
textelement = document.createTextNode(array[index].toExponential(3).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: I've just tried:textelement = document.createTextNode(array[index].toExponential(3).toUpperCase());
But still have lower case 'e' in the notation

Comment: @ViceNocillator It is impossible, it should work. What browser are you using ?

Comment: @ViceNocillator If this has solved your problem then you should accept the answer.

Comment: Sorry! I was editing the wrong file, not the one attached to the website. :P      Your solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

You have the ) in the wrong place

```
textelement = document.createTextNode(array[index].toExponential(3).toLocaleUpperCase());
```